# MySQL 8.0 row length (8,126 vs 65,535)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a wide table to be used for importing data before cleanup.  It has 221 columns of type `varchar(90)`, Innodb using Latin1.

When I try to create it, I get an error message `Error Code: 1118. Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB may help.`

But online help says that the max is 65,355.  As a matter of fact, if I try a simpler create statement as a test (below), I get a different error message: `Error Code: 1118. Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535.`

```sql
CREATE TABLE t (
  a VARCHAR(10000), b VARCHAR(10000), c VARCHAR(10000),
  d VARCHAR(10000), e VARCHAR(10000), f VARCHAR(10000),
  g VARCHAR(6000)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET latin1;
```

Why do I get different error messages that seem to indicate different max row lengths?

Comment: Why are you using such gigantic `VARCHAR` columns? Why not `utf8mb4` instead of the legacy `latin1` format? If you really need that much data you probably need a `TEXT` column instead.

Comment: Also 221 columns is just plain awkward and is surely a candidate for proper database normalization. Barring that you should evaluate if what you really need is a JSON column you can dump arbitrary data into in order to trim the column count down dramatically. Anything over 30 columns is usually a mess to work with.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.  I agree that no normal processing table should have so many columns.  This is an import table where we import a large csv that is received from a vendor, and then we normalize it into the appropriate tables.  We don't have any option to change the incoming format.

Comment: You can always do the pre-processing in a script before importing.

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 limitations:

- The MySQL max row size which is 65,535

  > The MySQL maximum row size limit of 65,535 bytes is demonstrated in the following InnoDB and MyISAM examples. The limit is enforced regardless of storage engine, even though the storage engine may be capable of supporting larger rows.
- The InnoDB max row size which is half of a page size (default 16k)

  > InnoDB restricts row size (for data stored locally within the database page) to slightly less than half a database page for 4KB, 8KB, 16KB, and 32KB innodb_page_size settings, and to slightly less than 16KB for 64KB pages.

MySQL will check first the global restriction and then engine restrictions as engine have equal or lower maximum.

Answer (score 3):

The MySQL architecture supports pluggable storage engines. This means there are limits at both the SQL layer and the storage engine layer.

The size limit of 8126 is in the InnoDB storage engine. This is the row size limit if you use InnoDB. The row size limit of 65355 is at the SQL layer, so no matter what storage engine you use besides InnoDB, it will only support rows of at most 65355 bytes (except for BLOB/TEXT).

You may be able set your InnoDB table to ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC. This changes the way it stores VARCHAR/BLOB/TEXT, and you may be able to store more columns that way.

But I would strongly recommend you reconsider a table design with 200+ varchar columns regardless of what storage engine you use. That really sounds like you haven't practiced good normalization for your design.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and advice.  I'll try the DYNAMIC setting and let you know how it works.
By the way, I'm 100% in agreement that this is an awkward table.  It's an import table to bring in data from a vendor.  Once it's in, we normalize it for ongoing usage, but we don't have any options on the incoming format.

Comment: I would write a script in Python or other favorite language, to parse the incoming vendor data file and insert data into the proper tables.